# Laravel5 : Calling a static method on eloquent model not working

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a static method in `User` model.

```
namespace Tol;
...
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    ...

    public static function signup(array $data)
    {
        $user = new User([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'type' => $data['type'],
        ]);

        $user->save();

        if ($user && $user->id) {
            $profile = new UserProfile([
                'first_name' => trim($data['first_name']),
                'last_name' => trim($data['last_name']),
                'gender' => $data['gender'],
            ]);

            $user->profile()->save($profile);

            EmailVerification::sendTo($user, 'signup');
        }

        return $user;
    }
    ...

}
```

And I'm trying to call call this method simply from my controllers.
like this

```
$user = User::signup($input);
```

And it throws error like this:
[image]

I don't know why it is referring it as a method on the Builder class. The code is very simple and everything was working when it was Laravel 4.

Please help.
thanks

Comment: Please re-attach the image of the error - it didn't come through.

Comment: @phpPhil. Please check this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0WsOG.png

Answer (score -1):

your code should have no problem, im afraid the problem is in your auth.php file, please ensure

```
'model' => 'App\User',
```

is set it to your model file in your case

```
'model' => 'Tol\User',
```

and to ensure your calling the right file you might want to give this a try

```
\Tol\User::signup($array);
```

Comment: it is already `Tol\User` in the `config/auth.php` file. And I've already tried `\Tol\User::signup` and it didn't work either.

Comment: i have tested your code in my environment, and they are running fine.

Which laravel 5 installation version you have ?
is `composer dumpautoload` helps ?